# Can't properly initialize Subscription ID API

Tags: java, android, api

Trying to get unique identifier of SIM card as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mobile-service-subscriptions). So I am trying to get this value on a phone with one sim, my code looks like this:

```java
package com.example.app;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SubscriptionInfo;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //checking for permissions
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS
            }, 121);
        } else {
            int id = this.subscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId();
            Log.e("Get_subscription_ID", Integer.toString(id));
        }
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==121 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //permision granted
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            int id = this.subscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId();
            Log.e("Get_subscription_ID", Integer.toString(id));
        }
    }
}
```

I have added also these lines to manifest

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

However, when I run this app and allow all of the permissions I get an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.telephony.SubscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId()' on a null object reference
```

As far as I understand I am calling `getSubscriptionId()` on the null object. Then I have tried to add `subscriptionInfo = new SubscriptionInfo();` to initialize object but then I get the error:

```
'SubscriptionInfo()' is not public in 'android.telephony.SubscriptionInfo'. Cannot be accessed from outside package
```

But when I check documentation I can see that this class is public ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionInfo#getSubscriptionId()))

What I am doing wrong here? I think I am missing something important

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be solved

```java
int simSlot = 0

SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = this.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInformation = sm.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(simSlot);
subscriptionInformation.getSubscriptionId();
```